# Extract part of a function output from package emmeans in R

Tags: r, function, printing, regression, subset

I was wondering how to extract the part titled `degree = linear:` from the output of `gg`?

```
library(emmeans)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat2.csv')

fit <- lm(math ~ time*ses + I(time^2)*ses, data = dat)

( gg <- emtrends(fit, ~ses, var= "time", max.degree= 2,at =list(ses=0,time=0)) )

degree = linear:
 ses time.trend      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL  
   0     0.3416 0.06084 1594   0.2222  0.46091  ##### Extract this part from `gg`

degree = quadratic:
 ses time.trend      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
   0    -0.0221 0.00835 1594  -0.0385 -0.00572
```

Comment: Try using `gg[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `summary` on `gg` and convert it into dataframe.

```
data.frame(summary(gg))
#  ses    degree  time.trend          SE   df    lower.CL     upper.CL
#1   0    linear  0.34156633 0.060844787 1594  0.22222212  0.460910546
#2   0 quadratic -0.02209907 0.008349954 1594 -0.03847712 -0.005721024
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(broom)
tidy(gg)
```